# Removing an app protected from uninstall by password and with System Owner permissions?

Tags: uninstallation, device-administrator, safe-mode, password-protection, development

I want to ask, if there is a way to remove an app that is protected from uninstall by password and has Device-administrator permissions granted? 
I am using an LG L90 phone with android 5.0.1 L (NOT ROOTED) Apparently it has a safe mode, as 1 year ago I accidently booted into it.

So here is the story what happpened:
I am developing an application that is supposed to limit access to for example work phones. It is password protected from uninstall, and I am regularly testing it on my phone. But in the most recent version, a bug slipped in which broke SHA256 hashes and caused passwords to be not recognized by the app, which means that I have locked myself out of games and youtube. Is there a way to remove this application? (Keep in mind that it has device administrator permissions and pops up with lock-out screens when on the "App uninstall" screen).

If the safe-mode thing could help, how would I boot into it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you can uninstall from the safe mode. Disable the authorization in the Device Administrator first.

*Step for booting in safe mode:*

- From any screen, press and hold the Power key.
- Touch and hold Power off. Review the 'Reboot to safe mode' screen,' then tap OK.
- The device should restart in safe mode and 'Safe mode' will appear in the lower-left.
- Uninstall the app that is causing a problem.

Comment: Thanks! You really saved my rear end. I will make sure to test the apps on emulators in the future.

Comment: How does one do so? EDIT: Nevermind, found it :)